# Find a uniform lower bound for a positive semidefinite matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove or find a counterexample that there exist a uniform constant $t>0$ for all positive semidefinite block diagonal matrix $H=\begin{pmatrix}H_1&&\\& \ddots&\\&&H_n \end{pmatrix}\succeq 0$ such that the following inequality holds:
\begin{align}
(H + \mu M)^2 \succeq t\mu^2 M^2,
\end{align}
where $\mu>0$ is a constant, $H=\begin{pmatrix}H_1&&\\& \ddots&\\&&H_n \end{pmatrix}\succeq 0\in \mathbb{R}^{nd\times nd}$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite block diagonal matrix with $H_i\succeq 0 \in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, $M = I_{nd} - Z \in \mathbb{R}^{nd\times nd}$ with $Z = e_ne_n^\top/n\in \mathbb{R}^{nd\times nd}$, $e_n = (I_d, \dots, I_d)^\top\in \mathbb{R}^{nd\times d}$, and $A \succeq B$ means that $A-B\succeq 0$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.

The matrix $M$ has some properties that might be helpful: (a) $M^2 = M$, (b) the eigenvalues of $M$ are $\lambda =1$ with multiplicity $(n-1)d$ and $\lambda =0 $ with multiplicity $d$, (c) $M e_n=0$.

Comment: Although we know that $H+\mu M \succeq \mu M$, we don't necessarily have $(H+\mu M) \succeq \mu^2 M$. But it seems promising since we just want a lower bound $t$, which can be related to $n$ or $d$.